# e13007f npn transistor datasheet reading for turn on time

Tags: transistors, datasheet, npn

I am reading datasheet for e13007. You can get it here: http://www.datasheet-pdf.com/datasheetdownload.php?id=520587
(click on "Download PDF for PC")

In "Electrical Characteristics" section under turn on time it says 1.6 us (max value). Now in the figure 4.(on page 2), I cant read this of the graph!
Curvers are for **tr** and **td**. I know that tr+td=turn_on_time. Reading the graph (for Ic=5A) I get
555us for turn on time. What am I doing wrong? Or what is turn on time for Ic=5A (one from the table or one from the graph or something else) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a typo- here is the curve from the similar part number [FJPF13007](https://www.fairchildsemi.com/datasheets/FJ/FJPF13007.pdf)

[image]

And your datasheet:

[image]

You may find it useful to refer to the [datasheet](http://www.onsemi.com/pub_link/Collateral/MJE13007-D.PDF) of the original manufacturer- it was Motorola, spun off some years ago as ON Semi.

Comment: Beat me to it. Found the same thing on the ON Semi datasheet, should be nano-seconds on the graph. Seemed pretty obvious to me that 1.6 uS was the only reasonable value. 550uS is kind of absurd...

Comment: What you guys suggest it what I've thought as well.